# Same code multiple times in my app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use the same code at many different locations in my app code. The code is very long and complicated and it's taking up a lot of space having the same code at multiple places.

Is there any way to make it into a function so I can type something like longCode; and it runs all the code I have written in the function when I defined it so I can save some space?

Comment: Yes. Make a class and put your code in some static method. Include your class wherever you want and just call like this [YourClass runMyLongCode];

Comment: It's not about saving space but not having to make the same change to multiple places when you need to change it.

Comment: I don't get the down votes.  While the answer is obvious to any experienced programmer, *it is a good question*, because the questioner realizes that the answer *should* be obvious.  This is the beginning of Wisdom!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. There is a lot of ways to do it.
For example creating class with one public static method.

```
@interface YourClass : NSObject

+ (int)longCode:(int)x;

@end
```

Now you can use your code just like:

```
int y = [YourClass longCode:x];
```

Answer (score 0):

you seemed to answer you own question in the question... put the code in a function, better yet a class/static function.

define a class function like so:

```
+ (returnType) theFunction: (SomeType*) aParameter {

}
```

define it in a header as well then you can just import the header

take a look [at this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Writing_Objective-C_Class_Methods) for more detail on it